# Cannot read property 'postMessage' of undefined

Tags: javascript

Getting the above error when trying to post message to web worker. Created the worker then trying to post message from within function. Exact code is pretty much as follows:

```
  var engine = new Worker("engine.js");
  function sendengine() { 
     engine.postMessage("hey"); 
     }
```

Comment: @JacobMattison He is using the browser's Web Worker. @Cherry, where you call the `sendengine` function?

Comment: What browser are you using?  Are you calling `sendengine()` before the line that sets `engine = new Worker("engine.js")`?  If so, do a check in `sendengine`, like `if (!engine) engine = new Worker("engine.js"); engine.postMessage("hey");`

Comment: I'm calling the sendengine function after starting the engine worker, and if i remove my postmessages going to the worker it runs smoothly and sends postmessages back to the main script without issue...

Comment: False alarm. I was calling the function before declaring the worker... Nothing to see here folks 8^)